# Object is opaque in viewport and semi-transparent in cycles render

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, transparency

I accidentally made an object semi-transparent.

I've been working on this Blender project on and off for several months. At one point I was trying to make an object semi-transparent so you could see through to the object inside of it. I must have had some success, since it renders semi-transparent in Cycles. The transparency does not show up in my viewport display. I have tried making the object opaque again, but I cannot remember what I did several months ago & I'm new to Blender. I've searched through many tutorials, but do not know how to fix this.

**Edit**: I'm working on this project for a lab, so I cannot share the file. Also, I was a bit unclear, the hair particles I added are visible in the final render (picture below), but the material texture isn't. My end goal is to create an animation where the skin/fur of the animal disappears to show the skull. For now, all I want is to render an image of the skin/fur that I have created, without the inner objects showing.

[image: Partial render]
[image: Viewport]
[image: Material nodes]
Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: hello, could you please show some screenshots, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Also, what do you want to achieve? Make the object opaque again, or transparency in viewport?

Comment: The only way to help you is if you [edit] your question and add more information. Show images of the material nodes, and also the full interface of the 3d viewport where you don't see the transparency (my guess is that you are in solid shading mode).